# Errors in rendering booklist to a template

Tags: django

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


booksList = [
              { 'id' = '1',
               'title' = "Beginner's Course in Django",
               'description' = 'Foundational Course in Django'}
                
              
              { 'id' = '2',
               'title' = "Intermediate Course in Django",
               'description' = 'Next steps in Django'
             },

             {
              'id' = '3',
              'title' = "Advanced Course in Django",
              'description' = 'The complexities of Django'
             },
     
              ]
```

I am rendering data to a template using the above bookList and getting two errors:

'[' was not closed Pylance  and
'{' was not closed Pylance

Kindly advise.

Comment: comma after the first dict

Answer (score 0):

I have just found the error: colon (:) should be used in place of the equal sign (=).The following code works:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


booksList = [
              { 'id' : '1',
               'title' : "Beginner's Course in Django",
               'description' : 'Foundational Course in Django'},
                
              
              { 'id' : '2',
               'title' : "Intermediate Course in Django",
               'description' : 'Next steps in Django'
             },

             {
              'id' : '3',
              'title' : "Advanced Course in Django",
              'description' : 'The complexities of Django'
             },
     
              ]
```